# P: SEPARAR 1s y 0s DE LA LISTA

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

una función que acepte como argumento una lista y retorne una tupla de dos listas.
La primera lista contiene todos los valores menores a 2 de la lista original.
La segunda lista contiene los índices de los elementos mayores a 1 en la lista original.
Ejemplo:limpiador_binario([ 0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 1, 0 ])=> ( [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ], [ 2, 4, 5, 6 ] )

Comment: Bienvenido Adrian a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas. Por favor agrega lo que hayas intentado o investigado hasta ahora, sino pareciera que  buscas que hagamos tu tarea. Saludos.

Comment: Algo no cuadra. ¿No seria `limpiador_binario([ 0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 1, 0 ])  ==> ([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [2, 5, 6, 2])` ?

Comment: Como tengo la ligera impresión que es una tarea sólo planeo dejar un consejo: `enumerate(lista)` entrega una tupla `(índice, valor)`.

Answer (score 0):

En Python puedes crear una lista con los elementos de otra que cumplan cierta condición.
Se llama [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
def limpiador_binario(lista):
    return ([i for i in lista if i < 2],
            [i for i in lista if i >= 2])
```

Fíjate que la condición que usamos es que sea menor que 2.
Si nuestra lista contuviera algún elemento negativo, también terminaría en el primer elemento de la tupla.
Si quieres que sólo contenga 1s y 0s, puedes escribir
`[i for i in lista if i in {0, 1}]`.

Comment: Recuerda siempre responder a preguntas _bien formadas_. OP no demostró qué fue lo que intentó ni qué problema tuvo :) Lee [answer].